# grep a log file for specific word that occured on today

Tags: unix

I have to search how many times we have received any specific exceptions on current date. I am using below command but it doesn't work.

This command shows `ClassCastException` or `NumberFormatException` that occurred until now.

I just wanted to know how many times `ClassCastException` or `NumberFormatException` occurred in today's date only.

```
grep $(date +"%Y-%m-%d") /*.* |grep  -ioh "ClasscastException\|NumberFormatException" /logs/*.* | sort | uniq -c | sort -r

grep -ioh "ClasscastException\|NumberFormatException" /logs/*.* | sort | uniq -c | sort -r
```

Above command gave me no of count for ClassCastException and NumberFormatException in log file for all dates. I just want for today's date count.

Answer (score 0):

The first command should work after removing the `/logs/*.*` part

`grep $(date +"%Y-%m-%d") /∗.∗ |grep  -ioh "ClasscastException\|NumberFormatException" /logs/∗.∗ | sort | uniq -c | sort -r`

grep works on the files that are given as argument, otherwise, it defaults to `stdin`.

Since files are supplied as argument to the the 2nd grep in this pipeline, it is discarding the output from the 1st grep and looking for the pattern in all files under log directory again.

Comment: /log/*.* is a log files directory path. *.* should search in all log files under unix log/ directory.

Comment: Then you can start the whole command line with it, like this:  `grep $(date +"%Y-%m-%d") /log/∗.∗ | grep  -ioh "ClasscastException\|NumberFormatException" | sort | uniq -c | sort -r`

Comment: grep $(date +"%Y-%m-%d") /apps/logs/*.* |grep  -ioh "Exception" | sort | uniq -c | sort -r

Comment: grep $(date +"%Y-%m-%d") /apps/logs/*.* |grep  -ioh "Exception" | sort | uniq -c | sort -r.  This looks working fine. In log file some contents are not inline with current date. They are under the current date line.Is there any way I could search data below the current date as well? sample data is as below ERROR 2015-10-31 18:39:25,817 [[.pausedEventAssetPollConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
*Exception stack is:
1. java.lang.ClassCastException@6ba3ac7b (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)

Comment: So a log entry spans multiple lines? Can you update the question with detailed examples from log files? How many lines per entry? What starts and ends an entry, etc. grep may not be enough for this, you may have to use awk or pcregrep or perl, etc.

Comment: grep -C 100 $(date +"%Y-%m-%d") /apps/logs/*.* |grep  -ioh "ClassCastException" | sort | uniq -c | sort -r. I tried this and it looks working